# Django manage.py makemigrations: Show differences between model and database

Tags: django, django-models, manage.py

I occasionally run into a problem where `manage.py makemigrations` will generate migrations that, as far as I can tell, concern models or model fields I didn't touch.
Is there any way to find out what differences between the model and the database `manage.py makemigrations` found, that make it think a migration is needed?

I searched the web and checked the django-admin and manage.py documentation but couldn't find a way to make `makemigrations` "explain itself" or to find differences between my models and database any other way.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python manage.py makemigrations --dry-run`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-makemigrations-dry-run

Edit:

I think there's some confusion here. Make migrations does not compare with the state of the database as such. It compares with the state of the models if you ran all existing migrations from scratch for that model.

So if the current migration gives you eg a CharField with length 30, and your current model definition has changed that to 32, `makemigrations` will give you the field change to 32.

So the migration you created (or the migration it shows you with `--dry-run` - same thing) - *is* the difference between what the DB should look like now and what your model looks like, assuming nobody has done any manual changes in the DB (which you absolutely should not if you are using a migration suite like the one django provices).

Comment: That tells me which migrations would be created. But what I want to know is *why* those are created. makemigrations compares the models and the database tables and, if it finds differences, creates a migration for it. I would like to know what differences it found.

Comment: That's pretty much the same thing. If you get a migration that is changing the field, it is because the field in your definition does not match the current state if you were to run all the migrations from scratch.

Comment: Aaah, thanks for the additional explanation! I indeed had the wrong idea about how makemigrations determines what migrations are needed and thus couldn't find any differences.